# DBeaver cannot connect to PostgreSQL with EOFException

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, pgadmin, dbeaver

I am trying to connect a database on Kubernetes (remote server) and I set all the necessary connection parameters on DBeaver. However, while I can connect the same database using pgAdmin, I cannot connect using DBeaver and it gives the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MRfT.png)

I checked many pages on the web and could not find a solution for that. I am not sure if it may be related to Driver, but I can connect to another PostgreSQL databases on my local Docker container.

Any idea to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case posgres was installed on VPS and wasnt configured to listen to calls from external IPs. Fixed by uncommeting "listen_addresses = ..." in /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf